# Scope with two parameters rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, filter, scoping

I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.justinweiss.com/articles/search-and-filter-rails-models-without-bloating-your-controller/) to implement a filtering feature in my Rails app. I want admins to be able to filter by age, identifier, and a date interval the users were created. It is the last bit that is causing me some headache.

In my model user.rb, I have defined the following scopes:

```
scope :created_between, -> (startdate, enddate) {where(created_at: startdate..enddate)}
scope :identified, -> { where.not(identifier: [nil, '']) }
scope :age, -> (age) { where("age > ?", age)}
```

In my controller users_controller.rb, I use a function to filter the params:

```
def search 
 filter = params.slice(:age, :created_between, :identified)

 filter.each do |key, value|
   if value.present?
        @users = @users.public_send(key,value)
   else
        @users = @users.public_send(key)
   end
 end
end
```

*I differentiate between a value present or not, since the :identified scope is implemented as a checkbox and therefore passes no value like*

Lastly, I have created a form for all the possible filters like so, in my view.html.erb file:

```
<%= form_tag users_search_path, :method => :get, :enforce_utf8 => false do %>
  <%= date_field :created_between, "from" %>
  <%= date_field :created_between, "to" %>
  <%= check_box_tag :identified, '', false %>
  <%= text_field_tag :age, "age" %>
<% end %>
```

The filter for age and identified works. When I submit the form the query becomes `/users/search?identified=&created_between[from]=&created_between[to]=` when I only check the checkbox identified (the date_field is also passed although I did not submit any date). And `/users/search?age=21&created_between[from]=&created_between[to]=` when I only submit an age.

**My problem is** that whenever I try to submit two dates for the `created_between` scope I get an `wrong number of arguments (1 given, expected 2)` error. I'm not sure that I'm submitting the date fiels correctly.

How can I pass the two needed params to the scope? Or should I do it another way instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes just writing out the question seems to make things clearer. However, the solution was to alter my scope function for `:created_between` to:

```
scope :created_between, -> (date) {where(created_at: date[:from]..date[:to])}
```

Comment: You have to use Javascript to disable the empty input field before submitting. `$(':input[value=""]').attr('disabled', true);`